# Navigation items blink for an unknown reason

Tags: css, grid, nav

I created a navigation menu with an animation hover effect that creates a moving underline under the hovered item. But when I hover on an item, the other items of the menu 'blink' as if they move a little bit out of their position and then come back. I have no idea why it happens: Here's my code:

```
nav a::before {
content: ' ';
display: block;
height: 3px;
background-color: #fff;
position: absolute;
bottom: -.5rem;
left: 0;
right: 0;
transform: scale(0, 1);
transition: transform ease-in-out 200ms;
}
nav a:hover::before {
transform: scale(1,1);
}
```

Of course it's just part of the code, if you would like to see more please tell me which part. I just didn't want to overwhelm.

HTML code:

```
<body>
 <header>
     <h1 class="logo">Logo</h1>
     <input type="checkbox" class="nav-toggle" id="nav-toggle">
     <nav>
         <ul>
             <li><a href="">בית</a></li>
             <li><a href="">על החנות</a></li>
             <li><a href="">מפה</a></li>
             <li><a href="">צור קשר</a></li>
         </ul>
     </nav>
     <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle-label"><span></span></label>
 </header>
```

Thanks a lot in advance,
Omer

Comment: please provide the corresponding html code

Comment: Just edited it in thanks

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked fine without any blinking of the other nav items. You might have to provide more of your CSS code because what you have above works fine.